# rails models has_many belongs_to relation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my three models/tables

```
class Swimming::Classschedule < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :swimming_classtimes ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime',:foreign_key => "classtime_id"  
  attr_accessible :id,:coach_id, :level_id, :note, :classtime_id
end


class Swimming::Classtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swimming_classschedules,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classschedule'
  belongs_to :swimming_timeblocks ,:class_name=>'Swimming::Timeblock',:foreign_key => "timeblock_id"    
  attr_accessible :date, :end, :start,:timeblock_id,:id
end


class Swimming::Timeblock < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swimming_classtimes,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime'
  attr_accessible :name,:id
end


swimming_classschedules belongs_to  swimming_classtimes 
swimming_classtimes belongs_to swimming_timeblocks
swimming_timeblocks has_many swimming_classtimes
swimming_classtimes has_many swimming_classschedules
```

How are swimming_classschedules and swimming_timeblocks associated ?

Comment: Do you mean how are `swimming_classschedules and swimming_timeblocks associated ` ?

Comment: @JSWorld yes, that is what I meant!

Comment: see my answer.. It is a `has_many :through` relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swimming_timeblocks has_many swimming_classschedules through swimming_classtimes

```
class Swimming::Timeblock < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :swimming_classtimes,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classtime'
 has_many :swimming_classschedules,:through => :swimming_classtimes
 attr_accessible :name,:id
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but how  come I added this line and I ran this `Swimming::Classschedule.joins(:swimming_classtimes).joins(:swimming_timeblocks).select("swimming_classtimes.*,swimming_timeblocks.*,swimming_classschedules.*").where("swimming_classtimes.date >= '2013-06-01' and swimming_classtimes.date <= '2013-06-08' ")`  I got an error message `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'swimming_timeblocks' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: Thanks. This is the code I added ` has_many :swimming_classschedules,:class_name=>'Swimming::Classschedule',:through => :swimming_classtimes `. It came with the same error message

Comment: can you try splitting into parts and see which part is actually causing the problem? I am not sure if the syntax you are using is right. Try `.joins(:swimming_classtimes => :swimming_timeblocks)‌` instead

Comment: it works! A bit more. Here is the result I got `=> [#<Swimming::Classschedule id: 7, coach_id: nil, level_id: nil, note: nil, created_at: "2013-06-08 23:24:31", updated_at: "2013-06-08 23:24:31", lesson_id: 1, classtime_id: 24,
lane_id: nil, program_id: nil, classtype_id: nil>]` I would expect to return all fields from three tables why I only got fields from the firt table?